# What does "If you can’t kill your enemy, weaken him. If you can’t cut off his head, take his heart" mean?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

This quote is from *Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1, episode 3 "Blood Ties":

> If you can’t kill your enemy, weaken him. If you can’t cut off his head, take his heart.

What does this mean? I thought of it as problem solving.

Answer (score 3):

> If you can’t kill your enemy, weaken him. If you can’t cut off his head, take his heart.

The sentence is from Sara Lance, aka White Canary, one of the heroes of the show.

The plot of Season 1 is to beat Vandal Savage. Remember that [Vandal Savage](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Vandal_Savage) is immortal. Precisely, he can live forever, as soon as he kills regularly ([This makes sense in context](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItMakesSenseInContext)) Sara's teammates Hawkman and Hawkgirl. He was born in Ancient Egypt millenia ago and since then, has lived in the shadow, to amass money, power and influence. This culminates at the beginning of the show when Rip Hunter, coming from the future, reveals that

> Vandal Savage will take over the world in the 22th century.

This is not a foe that can be taken lightly and the first attempts of the heroes to take him down failed. Before the beginning of the show, it took the forces of team Flash and team Arrow to beat him (backdoor pilot of *Legends of Tomorrow* and cross-over of *Flash* season 2 and *Arrow* season 4).

Sara's plan is to not confront Vandal Savage directly but to gather information and undermine his power. Their first attack (in [Season 1, episode 3](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Ties)) is to steal the money he uses to power his empire:

> **Rip decides to weaken Vandal Savage by going after his financial assets**. Rip and Sara infiltrate Savage's bank, but are discovered by his men.

Comment: It's like the Geneva Convention definition of terrorism vs. military action. If you attack the physical ability of your opponent, say by destroying a base full of tanks, that's military action. If you attack your opponents' willingness to fight, say by targeting civilians, that's terrorism.

Comment: @Covertwalrus: not here. The goal of Rip Hunter and the Legends is to take Savage's asset (financial assets in Season 1 episode 3 for example) in the same way the Western countries are trying to block Russian financial assets. In the Russian case, one could argue that this will affect Russian civilians as well, while it is not the case in Legends of Tomorrow (they try to harm him before he takes power).

Answer (score 2):

In most super hero situations it simply means kidnap Lois Lane/Mary Jane.

The traditional attack at the true weak point of a super hero is picking on those they love, attack the heart.

Comment: I don't think they would attack Kendra though. She is on the team, even if she is the only person Vandal loves.

Comment: -1. I will try to answer the question later, but the quote is from a hero of the show, not the villain.